# Eloquentsexual-but-mainly-for-teachers?

Tags: single-word-requests, is-it-a-word, synonyms

Little story first: every time someone asks me for my sexuality I either say bisexual (cause it's the easiest to explain) or that I don't label myself. Now this is not exactly accurate because I simply don't know a fitting word.
I know that there is a word for being attracted to someone smart but I've never found one for being attracted to someone who can simply talk well. (Especially teachers)
A friend and I were joking around the other day, and she made up the word *"eloquentsexual-but-mainly-for-teachers"*, which is kinda funny but sounds really stupid.

So my actual question would be: *Is there a word for it?*

If there isn't - which I suspect - I'd like a suggestion for a word. Eloquentsexual doesn't really feel right.

Comment: Most people who like women don’t like all women and the same for men whip like men. They may prefer only blondes or only athletic builds etc. But they don’t say they are *blonde-sexual*  It sounds like you are fundamentally bisexual with a taste for those who now how to perform ***oratio***...

Comment: I agree with Jim. One's sexuality is still, notwithstanding the increasing number of classifications of gender, defined by the sex or gender of the people you are attracted to, not their skills or physique. Those preferences could be classified as "taste". I'm a heterosexual, and that doesn't change if I am not sexually attracted to certain types of women. You may be looking for a word ending in _**-phile**_ rather than _-sexual_. Going with Jim's suggestion, you might consider _oratiophile_.

Comment: @oerkelens. Combining Latin (oratio) and Greek (phile) in the same word is really no-no.

Comment: @fdb Really? Someone should have told the person who coined automobile and television then. Or is it only acceptable if the Greek comes first? :P But if it really bothers you, how about _ritorophile_, neatly Greek/Greek?

Comment: @oerkelens. People who really care about language consider these (like sociology or homosexual) to be barbarisms. But we are a minority.

Comment: @oerkelens. But I would consider "rhetorophile" (thus spelt).

Comment: @fdb I certainly accept your spelling amelioration :)

Comment: @oerkelens. Greek actually has φῐλορήτωρ "lover of rhetoricians". So what about "philorhetor"?

Comment: @Jim What's this now about whipping men? ;-)

Comment: @tchrist - Stupid phone predictive keyboard...

Comment: @oerkelens I'm not so sure of that. So-called definitions lie somewhere between casual fictions and consent reality. These social identities aren't real, you know, which is what our poster is trying to explain to you that they recognize. The ancients would approve; those wrapped up in modern identity politics, not so much. Sapiosexuals are a thing.

Comment: @oerkelens You try telling that to the pizzasexuals of the world.

Comment: The OP says 'I know that there is a word for being attracted to someone smart ', but that this word is not quite right for the purpose. I assume that the word is *sapiosexual*. While eloquence and smartness are indeed conceptually distinct, they are correlated well enough that using *sapiosexual* may be close enough to the OP's intended meaning for the purposes of casual interaction, while being more readily understood, at least among those who are familiar with it (the term currently has only limited circulation), than any new term that one may coin to express the idea more precisely.

Answer (score 2):

Greek actually has φῐλορήτωρ "lover of rhetoricians". So what about "philorhetor"?

http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.79:8:6.LSJ

Comment: Seems legit. :-)

Comment: The OP is seeking a word that implies that the attraction is **sexual**; *philo-* does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

**Calliope**: "the muse who presides over eloquence and epic poetry"

or

> **Logophile**
> [law-guh-fahyl, log-uh-]/
> noun
>
> 1. a lover of words.

Comment: Isn't a logophile a lover of words, not a lover of someone who uses words well?

Comment: @AndrewLeach yes, that's true. But if it's the words that make her love the person, perhaps it is a sort of a transitive property?

Comment: Perhaps it's a logophilephile?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to coin a new word (which is fine) I would suggest "elequentosexual" with "o". This would conform better with the rules for Greek/Latin/English compounds. Which (I should think) is important for you in particular.

Comment: If combining Latin and Greek elements into a compound is a barbarism (it’s not—creating compounds from elements that originate in different languages is something that’s been done in all compounding languages since forever, and it’s a natural part of language development), then surely coupling athematic, third-class participles with thematic, second-class combining vowels is worse.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet. It is actually very common in Greek and Latin compounds to add the thematic vowel /o/ to an athematic Vorderglied. Witness physi-o-logist.